# Pivoting the table rows to colums

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

My table is as follows:

```
declare @tab TABLE (Id int, Rid INT, FValue VARCHAR(50), FText VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @tab VALUES
   (1,1,'Patient','P1'),
   (1,1,'Sdate','01/06/2023'),
   (1,1,'Acc#','123265'),
   (1,1,'Status','New'),
   (1,2,'Patient','P2'),
   (1,2,'Sdate','02/06/2023'),
   (1,2,'Acc#','512364'),
   (1,2,'Status','New'),
   (1,3,'Patient','P3'),
   (1,3,'Sdate','03/06/2023'),
   (1,3,'Acc#','632154'),
   (1,3,'Status','Complete')

select * from @tab
```

I tried pivoting it, using the following code, but without any success.

```
select RNo, Patient, Sdate, Acc#,[Status]
from
(
  select Rid, FValue, FText
  from @tab
) d
pivot
(
  max(Rid) for FText in (Rno, Patient, Sdate, Acc#,[Status])
) piv;
```

Output table should be:

```
declare @tab1 TABLE (Rno int, Patient VARCHAR(50), Sdate Datetime, Acc# VARCHAR(50), [Status] VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @tab1 
VALUES
   (1,'P1','01/06/2023','123265','New'), 
   (2,'P2','02/06/2023','512364','New'), 
   (3,'P3','03/06/2023','632154','Complete')

select * from @tab1
```

Comment: Can you check again the last three rows from your test data? What is the value for the Rid column - `2` or `3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple `PIVOT`, which turns the unique values from the `FValue` column into multiple columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT Id, Rid, FValue, FText
   FROM @tab
) t
PIVOT (
   MAX(FText) FOR FValue IN ([Patient], [Sdate], [Acc#], [Status])
) p
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated Query

```
    SELECT RNo, Patient, Sdate, [Acc#], [Status]
    FROM (
      SELECT Rid, FValue, FText
      FROM @tab
    ) AS src
    PIVOT (
      MAX(FValue)
      FOR FText IN (RNo, Patient, Sdate, [Acc#], [Status])
    ) AS piv;
```

The FOR FText in clause of the PIVOT statement should contain the column names from the FText column of your @tab table. The column names should be enclosed in square brackets if they contain special characters like "#" or spaces.

Comment: Thank you sir, but all rows are coming with value null

Comment: If all the rows are coming with NULL values after pivoting the table, it indicates that there might be an issue with the data or the pivot operation. Firstly, Check that the column names specified in the FOR FText IN clause of the PIVOT statement match the values in the FText column of the @tab table exactly. Any discrepancies in case or spelling can result in NULL values.
Secondly, Also check the data types of the columns in the @ tab table are compatible with the desired output.

Comment: Thirdly, see the values in the FValue column are not NULL or empty for the corresponding FText values. If there are missing or NULL values, the pivot operation may result in NULL values for those columns.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the spellings and values, all rows have values and spellings are also correct